# Remote form - XLSX download

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, axlsx

I have a form, where user can select values from collection of check boxes to filter data. Form posts to controller where xlsx format is defined to download xlsx file. I am using axslx_rails.

Now, I would like something to happen before and after the remote call.
And it works ok.

What I can't figure out is how to actually download a xlsx file as the respond block goes to JS format, not xlsx, which is something liek this:

```
format.xlsx { response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test.xlsx"'}
```

So, it works either one or the other way. Non-remote form downloads file as i have a format: xlsx defined. If i do a remote form, javascript works (show spinner, hide spinner, etc...), but file is not downloaded.

How can I achieve both?

Thx

Comment: paste the code from where you are sending a request for xlsx

Comment: `<%= simple_form_for :students, name: 'students_report', url: reports_students_report_path, method: :post, remote: true do |f| %>
...
<%= f.button :button, "Excel", id:"students_report_button", data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Generiram..."}, class:"btn btn-info btn-small" %>
`

Answer (score 0):

OK, i've given up and went with a solution:

- to save file to disk (to some publicly accessible location)
- download file via [jQuery fileDownload plugin](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/)
- delete file

Seems like the best solution currently for what i need.
If someone has a more elegant solution, without extra JS library involved...